# How do I instruct cabal-install or stack to use a local version of a hackage package?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Say I want to tinker with a few hackage packages that depend on each other and run

`stack unpack foo-1.2.0`

and

`stack unpack bar-1.0.0`

where `bar` depends on `foo`.

Now, to build my modified `bar` with my modified `foo`, I specify in my `bar.cabal`:

```
build-depends:

  foo == 1.2.0
```

and add to my `bar`'s `stack.yaml`:

```
packages:
  - .
  - rel/path/to/foo-1.2.0/
```

This works, and builds fine but it seems that if a dependency of `bar`, say `some-package`, itself depends on `foo` it will default to the hackage version rather than compile with my modified version despite my modified version meeting the version constraints. Is there a way to force other dependencies further up the chain to use my local version of the package during the build process? I appreciate this is a very unusual use case.

Weirdly I'm able to build fine but trying to load into `stack ghci` fails with:

```
Couldn't match type `foo-1.2.0:Some.Type.InFoo.aDataType`
               with `aDataType`
NB:    `aDataType` is defined at
       `full/path/to/foo-1.2.0/Some/Type/InFoo.hs:(23,1)-(28-60)`
       `foo-1.2.0:Some.Type.InFoo.aDataType`
         is defined in `Some.Type.InFoo`
            in package `foo-1.2.0`
       Expected type: `aDataType`
       Actual type: `foo-1.2.0:Some.Type.InFoo.aDataType`
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `stack` to me – I'd suggest that you report this. As a workaround you can probably turn the other reverse dependencies of `foo` into local package too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cabal User Guide](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/index.html), when developing a [project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build.html#developing-multiple-packages) with several [local packages](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build.html#local-versus-external-packages):

> Local packages, **as well as the external packages [...] which depend**
> **on them**, are built inplace, meaning that they are always built
> specifically for the project and are not installed globally.

So it seems that even external packages (that is, packages from Hackage or another package repository) will use the local packages, at the cost of needing to be rebuilt for the current project.